# Accessing dynamically created views

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am using a `linear Layout`(with some `imageViews`) into `ListView`'s `adapter`. With static `layout` everything works fine. But as I am creating dynamic `imageView`(s) I cannot access them from `getView(position, View, ViewGroup)` function simply by calling `findViewById(ImageViewId)`.
(Even though I get the view some other way, dynamic views are not showing in ListVeiw) I think I have to do something to add this views in Main View list, Any specific solution?

my code:

`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
    setLayout(2);
    setupListViewAdapter();     
    setGrid(bookCoverImages);   
}
```

Here dynamic imageViews are added:

`private void setLayout(int imageViews){
        setContentView(R.layout.default_book_view);`

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout11);

    int imgViewCounter=0;
    for(int i=0; i<imageViews; i++) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        ImageView image = new ImageView(WelcomeActivity.this);
        image.setId(i+100); param.weight=1;
        image.setLayoutParams(param); 
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        linearLayout1.addView(image);
    }

}

private void setupListViewAdapter() {
        adapter = new ImageListAdapter(WelcomeActivity.this, R.layout.default_book_view, new ArrayList<ImageRowBean>());
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_view);
```

}`

ImageListAdapter Class:

`public class ImageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
protected static final String LOG_TAG = ImageListAdapter.class
        .getSimpleName();

private ArrayList<ImageRowBean> items;
private int layoutResourceId;
private Context context;

public ImageListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<ImageRowBean> items) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;     
    try{
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    rowView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    ImageRowHolder holder = new ImageRowHolder();
    holder.imageRowBean = items.get(position);
    if(WelcomeActivity.windowWidth<500){

        holder.imageView1 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(100); //giving null here.
        holder.imageView2 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(101);


        holder.shelfImage = WelcomeActivity.imgViews[2];

        holder.imageView1.setImageBitmap(holder.imageRowBean.images.get(0));
        holder.imageView2.setImageBitmap(holder.imageRowBean.images.get(1));


    }   
    }
    catch(Exception e){ Log.d(" Excptopion  ", e.getMessage());}

    return rowView;
}

public static class ImageRowHolder {
    ImageRowBean imageRowBean;
    Map<Bitmap, String> imageMap;
    ImageView imageView1;
    ImageView imageView2;
    ImageView imageView3;
    ImageView imageView4;
    ImageView imageView5;

    ImageView shelfImage;
}
```

}`

Comment: One thing, The layout is not set as `setContentView()` and it wont be   added to main layout.

Comment: @323go please do have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a list of ImageView, you can create ImageViews and set their id, tags and onclicklistenners like this and add them to the ImageView list (I'll write examples what else can you set for dynamic views):

```
     imageList = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams param= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            ImageView img = new ImageView(WelcomeActivity.this);
            img.setId(i+100); 
            param.weight=1;
            img.setLayoutParams(param); 
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            img.setOnClickListener(customListenner);
            img.setAnimation(anim);
            img.setTag(i+100);
            linearLayout1.addView(img);
            imageList.add(img);
        }
```

and when you need to use the imageview again, just call with their id or tags from the list. (`imageList.get(0).getId()`)

If you need different listenners, you can control them by using the unique tag check in if function and declare another action.

This is the method that I always use when I need to create and use dynamic views programmatically.

Comment: I have done this `imageList.get(0).getId()`. It's get the ID but ListView isn't showing the view. Even-though if I give 1 static and 2 dynamic `ImageView`(s) inside a Layout, the static one is shown in list view and the dynamics are hidden.
The code in `getView()` is..

`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {//..... few other code`
   `holder.imageView1 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView11); // static imageView. showing ok`
   `holder.imageView2 = WelcomeActivity.imgViews[0]; // getting the imageView but hide in list view`
`return rowView;`
 `}`